# Triggering ng-change Event Programmatically From Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to trigger an ng-change event programmatically from some javascript.

This is the element I am trying to trigger the ng-change event for

```
<select ng-model="user.siteId" name="siteSelect" ng-change="user.setSelectedSite(user.siteId)" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Please Select A Site</option>
    <option id="siteOpts" value="1" ng-repeat="site in user.sites  | orderBy:'siteName'" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Site1</option>
    <option id="siteOpts" value="2" ng-repeat="site in user.sites  | orderBy:'siteName'" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Site2</option>#
    <option id="siteOpts" value="3" ng-repeat="site in user.sites  | orderBy:'siteName'" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Site3</option>
</select>
```

I know I can select a value using this code

```
document.querySelector('.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-empty').value = 2;
```

However this does not result in the ng-change event firing.

How can I select a value and ensure the ng-change event is fired?

Comment: the model value is being watched, set `user.siteId = 2` instead

Comment: @svarog how do I set a model value from JS? user.siteID = 2; does not work because user is not defined.

Comment: you do it in the controller, you define and object `user` and add a property `siteId` with the value 2, e.g. `$scope.user = {}; $scope.user.siteID = 2;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation

> The ngChange expression is only evaluated when a change in the input
>   value causes a new value to be committed to the model.
>
> It will not be evaluated:
>
> - if the value returned from the $parsers transformation pipeline has
>     not changed
> - if the input has continued to be invalid since the model
>     will stay null
> - if the model is **changed programmatically and not by a
>     change to the input value**
>
> Note, this directive requires ngModel to be
>   present.

What you can do is to manually call your function from your controller

```
user.setSelectedSite(user.siteId)
```

or use $scope.$watch.

Comment: thanks for the help, I got it working like this:

`angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]).scope().user.setSelectedSite(2)`

Comment: @user2976138 I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: .scope() is only available in debug mode